# change the width of inner div on click of outer div while creating custom seekbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I make a custom seekbar using two `div`'s one inside the another for an audio player. It is working well when playing song but I want to change the width of inner `div` when user click on a outer `div` (seekbar) and also change the time of audio.

Here is my code

```
<div id="progress">
<div id="myBar"></div>
```

```
#Progress
{
  position: relative;
  height:6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#myBar
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#progress").click(function(e){
      var xDistance = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var yDistance = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      $("#myBar").width(xDistance);
  });
});
```

```css
#progress {
 position: relative;
 height:6px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background-color: grey;
}
#myBar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress">
 <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but how i find the width where user click

Comment: I've updated the jQuery code to calculate the width based on mouse click. you can check that.

Comment: I used this updated code.But its not work .I want to increase the width of mybar where click is made.but its not work like this. i want to make a custom seekbar for audio.

Comment: I've already done that. Click on Run code snippet. You can see the width of child div i.e. myBar takes the width where user clicks. If you need complete HTML then its in 2nd answer over here.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right..but its not work for me may be the reason is dynamic ids i used

Comment: that might be a reason then.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong. Here is complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#progress").click(function(e){
                var xDistance = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var yDistance = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                $("#myBar").width(xDistance);
                console.log(xDistance);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #progress {
        position: relative;
        height:6px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        background-color: grey;
    }
   #myBar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="progress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```